# R data.table applying a function to subset of columns based on parameters from a list

Tags: r, data.table, apply, lapply

Assume I have the following data.table `z = data.table(val1 = 1:11,val2 = 3:13)`. In addition to this, I have a list of parameters which looks as follows `lambda = list(c(2,1),c(4,2))`. What I'm trying to accomplish is to apply a transform to both columns of the data.table as follows

```
val1 = val1^param1 + param2
val2 = val2^param3 + param4
```

where param1, param2, param3, param4 are stored as pairs in the list `lambda`. I tried the following but it gave me an error

```
z[,(1:2) := lapply(.SD, function(x,y) {return(x^y[[0]] + y[[1]])},lambda),.SDcols = 1:2]
Error in y[[0]] : attempt to select less than one element
```

Is there a way to do this cleanly/elegantly in data.table or using any of the apply functions? Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure of the efficiency of this, but working outside of data.table you could do:

```
Map(function(a,b) a^b[1] + b[2], z, lambda)
```

which could be adapted to

```
z[,Map(function(a,b) a^b[1] + b[2], .SD, lambda),.SDcols=1:2]
```